# For a natural number $n$ and numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \geq b \geq 0$, prove that $a^n-b^n \geq nb^{n-1}(a-b)$

Tags: analysis

I tried to do an induction proof and I've played around with it for about an hour and haven't really gotten anywhere.  For my base case, I let $n=1$ and got $(a-b) \geq (a-b)$, however when I tried to show $a^{k+1}-b^{k+1} \geq (k+1)b^{(k+1)-1}(a-b)$, I got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Apply the [mean value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) theorem on the function $f(x)=x^n$

Comment: A really clever way to prove this,well done!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+b^{n-1})$$